# Synonym for "Fellow Sufferers"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> They agreed to stay connected for hours in their provisional support group, looking for answers in their **counterparts**.

I want to change the bold part to say that they all shared the same problem. 
Might end up using one of the above, but I feel like I need some more options to weigh in.

---

**Edit for context**: they all share the same rare cognitive impairment

Comment: _comrades_, perhaps?

Comment: "Compatriots" is another option.

Comment: Or:  coequals, compeers, coordinates, counterparts, equivalents, fellows, like, matches, parallels, companions, cronies, hobnobbers, mates, allies, collaborators, confederates, buddies, chums, confidants, familiars, friends, intimates, pals.

Comment: @HotLicks Hey. Must be some group then.

Answer (score 5):

There's the straightforward [*co-sufferer*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Co-sufferer): "one who suffers with another." (Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I think it's just a little bit "dated, formal, poetic", but OED has

> **fellow** noun 5a
>   *One who shares with another **in any attribute**; one belonging to **the same class***
>   [emphasis mine]

Note that the near-equivalent [***peer***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/peer) *(someone/something of equal worth or quality)* usually implies equality in respect of something *desirable*, so it wouldn't necessarily work for OP's context (unless you *really* admire people who go to support groups! :)

But although *in principle* you could use unqualified ***fellows*** to mean *people with the same **drawback** [or advantage, background, etc.] as you*), in practice most people would go for

> [**fellow sufferers**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fellow%20sufferers%2Cfellow-sufferers&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfellow%20sufferers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfellow%20-%20sufferers%3B%2Cc0)

(Hyphenated or not - but as the NGram link shows, usually these days we *don't*.)

Comment: +1, FF, I feel "fellows" is best, but we native speakers wouldn't be likely to look for answers "in" our fellows so much as "from" or "among" our fellows, no?

Comment: @Little Eva: Yeah, I'd probably use ***from*** myself, but it kinda depends on exactly what nuance you want. To me, looking for answers ***in** [something, someone, some group]* more strongly implies ***you*** will "make the running" in the search (quizzing them, actively drawing out the answers). To get your answers ***from** [source]* suggests the source more proactively *pushes answers at you.* But that's just my take.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's what I was also thinking. Thanks ;]

Answer (score 2):

There is also [fellow](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/fellow%20victim) victims; [*fellow victims*](http://news.yahoo.com/writer-s-40-year-search-for-childhood-bully-connects-him-with-fellow-victims-190319294.html).

"Men weren’t really the enemy — they were fellow victims suffering from an outmoded masculine mystique that made them feel unnecessarily inadequate when there were no bears to kill." [Betty Friedan](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Betty_Friedan), The Feminine Mystique

Answer (score 1):

I would say ***in their peers.***

> peer *(n.)*:
>   1. one that is of equal standing with another :  equal;
>   especially :  one belonging to the same societal group especially based on age, grade, or status

The fact that there is a shared problem is already expressed by the phrase "support group".

Comment: I can't really endorse this one - as I pointed out in my own answer, unless used "facetiously", your ***peers*** almost always share something *advantageous* (or at least *neutral* - I don't really think it works when what you have in common is a ***problem***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Would you consider to visit this link? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_support

Comment: Actually, I'd forgotten about "peer support groups". But even though I'm quite familiar with that usage (effectively *adjectival*, equivalent to "self-help groups"). Years ago I did actually go to "group therapy" sessions, but  I personally probably wouldn't have referred to the other participants as my "peers".  Although maybe that's just because the sessions were overseen by a "non-peer" therapist. Whatever - I'm glad I didn't get carried away and downvote your answer, because it's obviously quite defensible. But I just wouldn't be likely to use it in OP's context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "That's not how we say it" is, obviously, a heavy blow, coming from a native speaker. To my understanding, however, you're making a weaker claim here: "That's not how I say it". Correct?

Comment: Yes, in light on your reminder about "peer support groups" I have slightly weakened my position (and edited my answer accordingly). It might be worth noting that we can and do skirt the issue using the compound noun *fellow sufferers*, but idiomatically you can't do that with *peer sufferers*. I would also add that I can more easily imagine a professional counsellor saying to someone in a PSG *"I think that's a matter you should discuss with your peers"* than the other guy saying *"Let me  discuss that with my peers"*. But I suspect they'd both probably say *"...with the peer group"*.

Comment: @anemone You can never have enough context, but I let my self cut back and ask for a synonym. The context does need something that indicates their common predicament which "fellow sufferers" has and peers doesn't. I was just feeling fellow sufferers might sound a bit wordy, or heavy.