# Someone who "does the same"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have the following sentence in mind:

> I talked with Mr. XY, a [word-request] doctor, and we came to the
>   conclusion...

What the [word-request] should state, is that I am a doctor and Mr. XY is aswell. I thought about "fellow", but somehow that doesn't seem to be the best option here in my opinion. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why does *fellow* not fit? (Aside from the subtle gender legacy.)

Comment: I think you're simply mistaken - [a fellow doctor](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+fellow+doctor%22) gets a claimed 4,010 results in Google Books. See [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/231945/2637) to a related / possible duplicate question.

Comment: *Fellow* might be inappropriate if the doctors are (for example) of medicine and archaeology respectively, of course, but I doubt that's the case here!

Comment: It's not that fellow **doesnt** fit - it's just that I have the feeling there actually **is** some other word I'm looking for. Could be that I'm wrong though ;)

Comment: How about *colleague* instead of *doctor* then, without anything in the place of [word-request]? You could then write "I talked with **Dr** XY, a colleague..."

Comment: @CharlE 'colleague' implies that the two people work together, not necessarily that their jobs are the same.

Comment: 'Fellow' is correct here. And it's a word I haven't yet added to the list of non-semantically-predicative adjectives I have somewhere. It doesn't so much describe an integral attribute of the referent of the noun, so much as the relationship of the referent to other contextual elements, stated or implied (cf mere youth, next train).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, ***confrere***

> *noun* A fellow member of a fraternity, profession, etc.; colleague:
>   *my confreres in the medical profession*.
>
> Origin of *confrere*: late Middle English Middle French Medieval Latin
>   1425-1475; late Middle English < Middle French < Medieval Latin confrāter colleague, equivalent to Latin con- con- + frāter brother
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/confrere)
>
> *I talked with Dr. XZ, a confrere, and we came to the conclusion...*

Answer (score 0):

"Another"

[M-W:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/another)

> similar or equal to a particular person or thing

Though it might seem a bit vague, in the absence of another aforementioned doctor, and after having established that the speaker is a doctor, the meaning should be clear enough.

"I talked with Mr. XY, another doctor, and we came to the conclusion..."

Comment: -1 Questioner states that the required word should indicate that BOTH of them are doctors.  Using "another doctor" could merely suggest that he's previously spoken to a doctor, not that he is a doctor.

Comment: I would argue that it can still be inferred.  If I told you, with no context, "I was having trouble with a problem, so I asked another programmer for help, and we were able to work it out."  You can probably infer what I do for a living.  In this context, so long as a third doctor has not been mentioned(there wasn't within the scope of the question), then the focus falls on the speaker.

Comment: @ ThunderGuppy  I don't disagree: it depends what has gone before, which we don't know.