# Word for people who have the same affliction

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose two people meet and learn that they both suffer from similar or analogous afflictions – e.g., they both:

- Spilled their meal on the floor.
- Have been walking through the same desert, both looking for something lost
- Are suffering from diseases with similar characteristics

Is there a single word that could allude to this relationship or the fact that they share a similar or analogous affliction or misfortune?

This is a more general case of [Synonym for "Fellow Sufferers"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/231937/67775)  Neither that nor "partners in misfortune" works because the people in question are not (necessarily) partners or fellows.  I don't want to assert more than that "they're in the same boat" (to incorporate the first answer).

<sub>E.g., none of the following attempts work: "We are affliction twins."  "She is my relationship sympathizer."  "You are my co-sufferer."</sub>

Comment: No, there is no such term.  Each condition is different, and even people who have "experienced" the "same" thing will often have vastly different experiences.  Being a rape survivor, or having a relative killed in by gunshot, or having had to escape from a war-torn city is not something that can be tossed into a neat little bucket.

Comment: @HotLicks - I bet there's a term in German.  And it sounds like you're getting distracted by the examples.  I'll replace them with less touchy ones.

Comment: Might I ask why co-sufferer doesn't work for you? It's valid, as far as an entry in Webster's makes a word valid...

Comment: @LiveMynd - Co-sufferer doesn't mean what I'm looking for: The people are not *suffering together* (although, when they *literally* share the same affliction, I suppose they may choose to).  They merely suffer from the same sort of thing.

Comment: To go with your italicized failed examples - "You're my companion in misery"?  "She's my broken-zipper buddy"?

Comment: @JohnFeltz - Yes, those are on the right track!  "Broken-zipper buddies" is especially good, and I was going to use that formulation, except that when the affliction can't be reduced to a compound word it doesn't really work.  (E.g., "She's my wandering-the-desert-looking-for-something-lost buddy....")

Answer (score 2):

It's not a single word (but neither are most of your attempts), but I would use the idiom **in the same boat**. [Wictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_the_same_boat) gives the definition:

> In the same situation or predicament; having the same problems.

Comment: Yes, that is a good idiom for what I'm seeking.